# NullPointerException not printing custom MappedLoggingContext

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have a code for setting MappedLoggingContext as follows :

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper req = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper res = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        contentTrace = new ContentTrace();
        contentTrace.setTimestamp(DateUtils.currentTimestamp());
        try {
            MappedLoggingContext.clearContext();
            String traceId = request.getHeader("***");
            MappedLoggingContext.setAPIDetails(request.getRequestURI(), request.getMethod());
            MappedLoggingContext.setTraceId(traceId);
            super.doFilterInternal(req, res, filterChain);
        } finally {
            MappedLoggingContext.clearContext();
        }
    }
```

However, I have noticed that incase of  NullPointerException, these details go missing. My knowledge of this is limited and would appreciate any clue on how to solve this.

Let me know if adding logback-spring.xml file's content would be any helpful in determining the cause. Thanks.

Edit#1

Typical log in NPE looks like this :

> {   "app": "**",   "ts": "2022-11-20T11:35:36.269Z",   "logger":
> "org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]",
> "level": "ERROR",   "class": "org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog",
> "method": "log",   "file": "DirectJDKLog.java",   "line": 175,
> "thread": "http-nio-5000-exec-5",   "stack":
> "java.lang.NullPointerException: null\n",   "msg": "Servlet.service()
> for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
> exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause" }

Comment: can you provide a stacktrace of the `NullPointerException` or any other logging message?

Comment: @luckyluke have added in edit. Do you think this omission is due to JVM optimisation?

Comment: hi @ishallwin - no - this is caused due logging configuration. The source of the class which is loggin this is [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/juli/logging/DirectJDKLog.java#L175). Check your settings, if they contain any [json formatter](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output#2-configuration-1) and try to configure [normal formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html)